# Creating new Tshape component problem ,Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, components, shapes

Am creating new Shape Component ,its name : Device Shape , but the component didn't registered and its not appear in the components plate.

The code were compiled without any errors , but I could not register the new component .

can anybody help.

```
unit DeviceShape;
interface
uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Classes,
  Graphics, Controls,ExtCtrls;
  type
 TdeviceType=(Smoke,Heat,Control_Module,Monitor_Module,Bell,Break_Glass,Sirin);
 TdeviceShape=class(TShape)
private
   FDevType:TdeviceType;
   FdeviceTxt:string;
   procedure  SetDeviceTxt(Value:String);
   procedure SetDeviceType (Value:TdeviceType);
public
    constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
 protected
 procedure Paint; override   ;
 published
    property Text: string read FdeviceTxt write SetDeviceTxt default 'S' ;
    property DeviceType:TdeviceType read FDevType write SetDeviceType default Smoke;
    property OnClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
end;
procedure register ;
implementation
    procedure Register;
begin
RegisterComponents('Issam', [TdeviceShape]);
end;
```

and here you can find the next procedures body :

```
procedure TdeviceShape.Paint;
begin
Canvas.Font.Height:=Width-(Width div 4) ;
Canvas.TextOut(0,(Height div 2)-(Canvas.Font.Height div 2),FdeviceTxt);
inherited;
end;
procedure TdeviceShape.SetDeviceTxt(Value:String);
begin
case FDevType of
Smoke             : FdeviceTxt:='S';
Heat                  : FdeviceTxt:='H';
Control_Module : FdeviceTxt:='C';
Monitor_Module : FdeviceTxt:='M';
Bell                    : FdeviceTxt:='B';
Break_Glass     : FdeviceTxt:='BG';
Sirin                : FdeviceTxt:='SI' ;
end;
Invalidate;
end;
procedure TdeviceShape.SetDeviceType(Value: TdeviceType);
begin
  if FDevType <> Value then
  begin
    FDevType := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Did you put it in a package? Do you have a `Register` procedure? Did you install the package?

Comment: Yes. sorry i have tried to attach the code ... but the site asked for more details ..

Comment: Well, then you should have followed the advice and provided more details. All relevant code (in particular the `Register` procedure), and a description of *how* you tried to install the component: units, packages, approach (such as right-clicking package and selecting "Install"), and also a description of what happened: the text of the message displayed.

Comment: I have reduced the attached code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation on registering components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_the_Register_Procedure):

> Registration involves writing a single procedure in a unit of your package, which must have the name **Register**. The **Register** procedure must appear in the interface part of your unit, and (unlike the rest of Delphi) its name is case-sensitive.
>
> **Note**: Although Delphi is a case-insensitive language, the **Register** procedure is case-sensitive and must be spelled with an uppercase `R`.

So it seems like you need to write `Register` instead of `register` in the interface section.

Comment: Also, you really should be more careful when it comes to code formatting! A very important part of being a software developer is caring about details. There are *way* too many issues for me to be able to point them all out in a comment, but here are a few examples: (1) Why are there *two* spaces in front of `SetDeviceTxt`? (2) Why do you sometimes have and sometimes not have a space before `(`? (3) After `:`? (4) Before `;`? (5) After `,`? (6) Why do you sometimes write `String` with capital `S`? And so on. I really do think attention to detail correlates with end-result quality.